# Make a donut with minimum number of nodes

Tags: shaders, geometry-nodes

I see that code-golf is very popular in SA. There is even a community related to it: https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/ So inspired by tutorial about making donuts using volume shader https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eJLsr3boqWY I think it would be great to try this format in Blender.

So you have to make a donut with uneven glaze, and 2 types of sprinkles, just like Blender Guru's one:

[image]

You can use Geometry Nodes or Shader Nodes, (or any other node system) it should be nice to compare. Nice that Geonodes haven't torus primitive, so there's no head start here.

Here are basic rules:

- Use a default cube, do not edit mesh or UV
- Using any additional geometry is not allowed
- Grouping nodes is not allowed
- Reroutes doesn't count
- Materials are not required, but you should color each part (torus, glaze and sprinkles) of the mesh in a different color, sprinkles - random color.
- Post the number of nodes (including input and output), screenshot of the nodes, resulted donut and blend file (https://blend-exchange.com/)
- Node setup with minimum number of nodes wins!

This is a first time that node golf is starting, so rules may be corrected

You can count your nodes by typing this in Blender console:

```
len([n for key, n in D.node_groups['Geometry Nodes'].nodes.items() if n.type!='REROUTE'])
```

[image]

Comment: Never thought a day would come where I'd be actually happy to see a donut post.

Comment: Someone should finally set a somewhat healthier trend in the world, with all the obese people. How about fresh fruit or vegetables? ...Therefore, I do not participate.

Comment: Well the form is quite simple and difficult in the same time, and all features are appealing. So I believe it is one of the best form as for learning blender as for nodleing

Comment: And your question is?? :^))

Comment: @JohnEason the question is who will earn 500 reputation points!

Comment: Ok. So your answer to gain points is? :^)

Comment: @JohnEason I already have my answer, and waiting for yours =^)

Comment: I  think I'll pass on that one! - Too many other things to do at the moment... (Plus the fact that I don't have 3.3 yet.)

Comment: @JohnEason this is not required, In my setup I've used volume cube, you may not use it!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138389/discussion-between-john-eason-and-crantisz).

Answer (score 5):

> **Out of score due to rule changes** (randomly colored sprinkles)!

## 17 Geometry nodes, 3 shader nodes

...no comment...

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2)*</sub>

Comment: @Crantisz ...I think it can't be less nodes, but it's actually a pity that we two are the only ones participating in this challenge. ...I like this new tag ;-) ...At least once this donut question is clarified.

Comment: It would be nice if this nice little bounty attracts more people

Comment: @Crantisz You created this tag didn't you? ...I'm sure we'll have some great ideas for it as time goes on :D

Comment: Yes. This donut hasn't random colors on sprinkles, so it definitely would not be count

Comment: you could attract more people easily by offering real donuts.... :D :D :D

Comment: @Chris Sure, I will send it to you by email :D

Comment: @quellenform: now you disappointed me for the first time. That's not funny!!! 

Comment: @Chris Sorry, that was a stupid joke, of course I will personally come over and bring the donuts on a silver platter... 

Comment: Na geht doch! Warum denn nicht gleich so?!‍♂️

Answer (score 4):

## 27 Shader nodes

This donut made without using Geometry nodes:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow! And this should fix it for @quellenform's diet! All he needs to do is turn the density down, and he gets a Vapo-Nut.

Comment: Haha, cool! ...this looks like a "Geometry vs. Shader" battle to me :D

Answer (score 3):

## 32 Geometry nodes, 3 shader nodes

Try to beat this!

[image]

[image]

[image]  Blender 3.3 required

Answer (score 3):

## 30 Shader nodes

This method uses Vector displacement

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: ....You're probably dreaming of donuts by now, right? :D

Comment: For now, I have 4 styles to do one particular thing using nodes. This is called diversity.

Comment: wow amazing! but just for understanding, why won't eevee support displacement? it stays cubic in eevee.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie Displacement seems to not work in EEVEE

Answer (score 2):

## 19 Geometry nodes, 3 shader nodes

*Challenge accepted, this is the first and last donut I build. Disgusting stuff...*

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2)*</sub>

---

> **Important notice from the Ministry of Health:**.
>
> Donuts are NOT food, but sweets!
>
> They contain a disproportionate amount of sugar and fat, which can lead to significant health risks and even premature death if consumed excessively and regularly!
>
> For a balanced and healthy diet, the abandonment of sugared foods and a return to organic farming and the consumption of food grown sustainably and as natural as possible should be sought.

Comment: 2 types of sprinkles - it is important because affects on node count. Please add them and update node count

Comment: @Crantisz ...there are two types of sprinkles: spheres & cones ;-)

Comment: Oh. yes... but... :-)

Comment: you could save one node by using Sverchock -> which has a torus node ;) and with that result you could add your GN modifier without the 3 nodes to create the torus...so in total it would be one node less....but...no default cube. [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p66tk.png

Comment: @Chris Haha, yes, that would be the solution! ...but I guess then Crantisz would have to adjust the rules again :D

Answer (score 2):

## 28 Geometry nodes, 3 shader nodes

...one more to go:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2)*</sub>