# How to Create Procedural Snowflake like Pattern with Shader Nodes

Tags: shaders, procedural

**I'm trying to create a snowflake shape procedurally with Blender's shader nodes.**

I have a general idea on how it would be created. Somehow I'd need to make the blocky shape thats on the edge of each piece, and then mirror that shape to the other side, so that it's symmetrical. Then I'd need to array and rotate that shape around the center to finish the snowflake shape. But I'm having a hard time figuring out how to make it.

I've attached a photo of the look that I'm going for. It doesn't need to look exactly like the photo, but just something close to that. A simple snowflake shape.
Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After finding this [amazing tutorial](https://youtu.be/QZiVXcrsvPM) by Luca Rood on Creative Shrimp's YouTube channel, I was able to make a simple result that I'm happy with. (See Screenshot Below)

**11 Procedural Shading Tips in Under 10 Minutes:** https://youtu.be/QZiVXcrsvPM

[image]

Comment: cool thanks for sharing! pretty amazing what we can do with shader nodes.. check this one out, they made a donut using only shader nodes XD https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/271865/142292